# how to create dynamic url using get Route rather then id in Laravel 5.6

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.6, dynamic-url

i want to create dynamic URL Route rather then id. I want to create url column in database i want use that column to create url in route.

```
Route::get('our-services/{service}', 'ServiceController@show');
```

it's my route code, using this route url look like this

```
127.0.0.1:8000/1
```

but i want to create like this,

```
127.0.0.1:8000/name
```

it's my link code that are create dynamically

```
<a href="{{url('our-services/'.$service->url)}}" class="small white uppercase font-weight-6 underline">Read More</a>
```

it's dynamic url that create from database colum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) to customize the resolution logic. In the RouteServiceProvider boot method:

```
Route::bind('service', function ($value) {
    return App\Service::where('url', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```